# Is a Master 2 Research (Europe) a University or Postgraduate Degree?

Tags: postdocs, degree, administration

I am currently applying for post-docs and for one of them, I should provide the "category" or degree/educational establishment where I have the choice between:

```
University degree
Postgraduate
PhD
```

My question is: what is the right category of a Master 2 Research (in Europe) ? 
Is it a University degree or a Postgraduate degree ?

Comment: I would consider that a postgraduate degree, as it's a degree obtained after you achieved your bachelor's degree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I would recommend you to confirm, normally a 'university degree' is an undergraduate degree.

A postgraduate could be a postgraduate certificate, postgraduate diploma, or a postgraduate degree (which is a master degree)

I think you know what a PhD is.

In short, as master is a postgraduate (the middle of your three choices).

It seems a little strange because normally post-docs are **post** (after) **doctorate** (PhD).

Comment: Thanks. In fact, this is not strange because it asks for details on the last degree (PhD) but also previous ones (Master's).